# ajax not generating content dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am working on an ajax based html form to fetch some data from database and show it.

In my data retrieve part of the form. the data that's fetched from the database is not rendered by the ajax code. When data is fetched, the div part that is extended that I can see because of the bg color but there is no table of data.

Here is my code: How to make it working ?

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="Browse Record" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="row" id="meta-update">

     <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
      <h6> Fields </h6>
     <div id="browse" class="col mb-4"> 

   <div class="records_content">  </div>

</div>
 </div>
</div></div>
```

**JS:**

```
function insertRecord() {
    // get values
        var field_id = $("#field_id").val();
        var description = $("#description").val();
        var corner_points = $("#corner_points").val();
        var dldm = $("#dldm").val();
        var pdm = $("#pdm").val();
        var notes = $("#notes").val();

    // Add record
        $.post("ajax/insertRecord.php", {
        field_id: field_id,
        description: description,
        corner_points: corner_points,
        dldm: dldm,
        pdm: pdm,
        notes: notes

    }, function (data, status) {

    // read records again
        readRecords();

        // clear fields from the popup
        $("#field_id").val("");
        $("#description").val("");
        $("#corner_points").val("");
        $("#dldm").val("");
        $("#pdm").val("");
        $("#notes").val("");

    });
}


// READ records
function readRecords() {
    $.get("ajax/readRecords.php", {}, function (data, status) {
        $(".records_content").html(data);
    });
}
```

**readRecord.php:**

```
<?php


// include Database connection file 
    include("ajax/connection.php");

    // Design initial table header 
    $data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Field-ID</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Corner-Points</th>
                            <th>distance_map</th>
                            <th>Piping_map</th>
                            <th>Notes</th>
                        </tr>';

        try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT field_id, description, corner_points, damming_level_distance_map, pipeline_distance_map, notes FROM fields");
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {

                 $data .= '<tr>
                <td style="width:150px;border:1px solid grey;">'.$row['field_id'].'</td>
                <td style="width:150px;border:1px solid grey;">'.$row['description'].'</td>
                <td style="width:150px;border:1px solid grey;">'.$row['corner_points'].'</td>
                <td style="width:150px;border:1px solid grey;">'.$row['damming_level_distance_map'].'</td>
                <td style="width:150px;border:1px solid grey;">'.$row['pipeline_distance_map'].'</td>
                <td style="width:150px;border:1px solid grey;">'.$row['notes'].'</td>

            </tr>';

            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            // echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
               exit('<b>Catched exception at line '. $e->getLine() .' (code : '. $e->getCode() .') :</b> '. $e->getMessage());

        }

    $data .= '</table>';

    echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: Where readRecords() is defined in JS? Also you're wrongly concatenating $data varibale in foreach loop.

Comment: I added the js code in the post. At the bottom of the code, readRecords() is defined. Can you please put correct way of concatenation of $data.

Comment: Could you check in your browser if the request is made properly and contains the expected response?

Comment: @NicoHaase: What you mean by request and response ?

Comment: Well, you are doing an AJAX request (which is sent to the browser). And debugging such requests should involve checking the browser's network console for the proper request parameters (to be sent to the browser) and the proper response by the server (containing the rendered response)

Comment: I check the browser network console i.e. I used f12 on chrome to open it. In the network tab, the request headers have status of 200, response headers also has same.

Comment: And what about the content of that response? The headers are, more or less, not interesting currently

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186800/discussion-between-xceptable-and-nico-haase).

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing PHP variables wrong

**What I mean is:**
You have this:
`<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['field_id'] ?></td>`
While it should be:
 `<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'>'.$row['field_id'].'</td>`

Another problem is that the quotes are escaping. Use double quotes `"` or `\` to prevent this:

Double quotes:
`<td style="width:150px;border:1px solid grey;">`
Single quotes escaped:
`<td style=\'width:150px;border:1px solid grey;\'>`

And the line `$data .= ''` should end with a `;`.

Comment: I made the changes you mentioned in all fields in php file including field_id and added ; too, but still it's not printing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Update PHP foreach loop with following

```
foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) 
{

    $data .= '<tr>
        <td style="width:150px;border:1px solid grey;">'. $row['field_id'] .'</td>
        <td style="width:150px;border:1px solid grey;">'. $row['description'] .'</td>
        <td style="width:150px;border:1px solid grey;">'. $row['corner_points'] .'</td>
        <td style="width:150px;border:1px solid grey;">'. $row['damming_level_distance_map'] .'</td>
        <td style="width:150px;border:1px solid grey;">'. $row['pipeline_distance_map'] .'</td>
        <td style="width:150px;border:1px solid grey;">'. $row['notes'] .'</td>                    
    </tr>';

}
```

Comment: After this i believe you are not parsing response properly in JS.

Comment: can you please tell some solution for that.